# Retrieve old sp name when i wrongly update the sp name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

While selecting the sp name by using **Rename**, i wrongly press 's' and press tab. Then it is renamed wrongly. I don't know the Sp Name. How do i get the old sp name. Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN I found in [sp_rename (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188351.aspx)

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not
>   change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition
>   column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view. Therefore, we recommend
>   that sp_rename not be used to rename these object types. Instead, drop
>   and re-create the object with its new name.

I have tested the same and I got old object name.

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_MY_SP
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS COL
END


GO
SELECT OBJECT_ID('PROC_MY_SP')  --789786071
GO

SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE OBJECT_ID('PROC_MY_SP')= OBJECT_ID

GO
sp_rename 'PROC_MY_SP', 'PROC_YOUR_SP'

GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('PROC_YOUR_SP')  --789786071
--Changing the SP Name wont change the objectID

GO
SELECT definition,* FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE OBJECT_ID=789786071
--Or Simply pass your new sp name
SELECT definition, * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE OBJECT_ID('PROC_YOUR_SP')= OBJECT_ID
```

Here the definition column showing the old sp name only.